# How can I change the chapter number in a book environment?

Tags: chapters, book-design

I want to change the chapter number so that when I compile the code, the document starts at the 2nd, 3rd or any other chapter number.

What's the better way to do this?

Comment: Try `\setcounter{chapter}{2}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\c@chapter` is the counter which stores the current chapter number. To modify this, you have to use

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setchapter}{\afterassignment\fixch@pter\c@chapter}
\newcommand{\fixch@pter}{\advance\c@chapter by -1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setchapter=4
\chapter{My Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly man, thanks!

Comment: Technically, `chapter` is the counter name, and `\c@chapter` is the count register.